# Files not being parsed by Gnatchop

Tags: ada, gnat

**Gnatchop** - I am trying to run several files through gnatchop and I am getting 3 error messages for every file. I originally thought that the error was simply the permissions were wrong. But I changed the permissions and I still get the errors.

```
file.a: parse errors detected
file.a: chop may not be successful
file.a: error parsing offset info
```

Is there something I need to do to the files before I run them through Gnatchop?

Comment: It seems that `gnatchop`'s internal invokation of `gcc` either fails or returns with errors. Can you manually check the output of this `gcc` command by invoking it yourself? The command `gnatchop` invokes can be made visible by adding the verbose switch `-v` to `gnatchop`; its something like `gcc -c -x ada -gnats -gnatu file.a`. The output of this command should be something like `Unit ... (spec) line ...`.

Comment: Running the command returns
`no compilation units found`
`no source files written`
which I am assuming means the files I am trying to chop have no Ada components in them?

Comment: I actually ran the gcc call. The error it returns is _fatal error, run time library not installed correctly, cannot locate file system.ads._ I have solved this problem in the past by setting the --RTS flag on other gnatchop commands but my version of gnat(4.8.5) does not have that flag.

Comment: First of all I assume that the `.a` files contain Ada source code (e.g. Ada packages (spec/body) and/or subprograms). If not, then chopping is more or less pointless. Regarding the RTS problem: some solutions seem to [exist](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gnat_ugn_unw/Search-Paths-and-the-Run-Time-Library-_0028RTL_0029.html), but this might get complicated. If this is your own (personal) computer, then I would recommend to reinstall GNAT. If not, then this might be a special GNAT setup. In that case, please ask a system admin.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the suggestion on using the -v switch that actually has helped a lot. I will follow the run time path problems which more than I before. Thank you again.

Comment: Presumably you can’t compile Hello_World, then. That’s a seriously broken GNAT installation. What OS are you using? which GNAT distribution, if not the one that comes with the OS?

Comment: I am using CentOS 7.6. Gnat 4.8.5 I did install it using the base repos available to the OS. I have read that a **Ada_source_path** and **Ada_lib_path** files were supposed to be created on installation and that these files provide the runtime paths when I am building Ada projects. I cannot find these files in my file system maybe I am misunderstanding what these files really are.

Comment: Normally when you install Ada as part of GCC the runtime is installed alongside automatically, in a place where the compiler can find it without you needing to do anything special. Are you sure you didn’t miss some "Ada development libraries" package or some such? I don’t know CentOS or Red Hat so can’t help further.

Comment: When I installed it, I installed gcc-gnat, which also required libgnat-devel and libgnat(which includes the runtime shared libs). But so far I have needed to add the RTS switch to gnatmake and gnatbind for it to find the path to the runtime.